# functional programming and python pandas dataframes in pipelines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming, pipeline

I was wondering which is the best practice of functional-programming to write a pipeline of functions which process pandas dataframes - or any other mutable input types - as input of functions.

Here are 2 ideas but hope that something better exists :)

idea # 1 - no functional programming but saving memory

```
def foo(df, param):
    df['col'] = df['col'] + param

def pipeline(df):
    foo(df, 1)
    foo(df, 2)
    foo(df, 3)
```

idea # 2 - more functional programming but wasting memory by doing .copy()

```
def foo(df, param):
    df = df.copy()
    df['col'] = df['col'] + param
    return df

def pipeline(df):
    df1 = foo(df, 1)
    df2 = foo(df1, 2)
    df3 = foo(df2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dataframe is 1-dimensional (that is it is a list of items) then you can instead of applying multiple 'pipes' do everything in one single go. For example we are given a dataframe

```
>>> table
     Name  Year of Birth      City
0    Mike           1970  New York
1   Chris           1981     Miami
2  Janine           1975   Seattle
```

We want to calculate the age and check if one lives in Miami. You can apply 2 pipes but it can be done with a single lambda:

```
>>> f = lambda s: pd.Series([2019 - s['Year of Birth'], s['City'] == 'Miami'])
```

Then apply it

```
>>> table[['Age', 'Lives in Miami']] = table.apply(f, axis=1)
>>> table
     Name  Year of Birth      City  Age  Lives in Miami
0    Mike           1970  New York   49           False
1   Chris           1981     Miami   38            True
2  Janine           1975   Seattle   44           False
```

All the work is done in `f`.

Another example: Say you want to check who is over 45 years old. This contains two **serial** operations (the previous example was 2 **paralel** operations):

1. Calculate age
2. Check if age is bigger than 45

You could use 2 pipes but again it can be done by applying a single lambda which does it all:

```
>>> table
     Name  Year of Birth      City   
0    Mike           1970  New York            
1   Chris           1981     Miami           
2  Janine           1975   Seattle      
>>> g = lambda s: pd.Series([2019 - s['Year of Birth'] > 45])              
>>> table['Older than 45'] = table.apply(g, axis=1)
>>> table
     Name  Year of Birth      City  Older than 45
0    Mike           1970  New York           True
1   Chris           1981     Miami          False
2  Janine           1975   Seattle          False
```

If you prefer immutability then do

```
>>> table
     Name  Year of Birth      City
0    Mike           1970  New York
1   Chris           1981     Miami
2  Janine           1975   Seattle 
>>> pd.concat([table, table.apply(f, axis=1)], axis=1)
     Name  Year of Birth      City   0      1
0    Mike           1970  New York  49  False
1   Chris           1981     Miami  38   True
2  Janine           1975   Seattle  44  False
```

If you don't like lambdas then define

```
def f(s):
    return pd.Series([2019 - s['Year of Birth'], 
                      s['City'] == 'Miami'])
```

This all only works when you want to apply a mapping which only needs to work on a single individual row. Also, I don't make any claims on speed, pipes might be faster, however this is very readable.

*(And in the end you realize you'd better of using Haskell.)*

Answer (score 7):

You can chain function calls operating on the dataframe. Also take a look at `DataFrame.pipe` in pandas. Something like this, adding in a couple of non-foo operations:

```
df = (df.pipe(foo,1)
      .pipe(foo,2)
      .pipe(foo,3)
      .drop(columns=['drop','these'])
      .assign(NEW_COL=lambda x: x['OLD_COL'] / 10))
```

`df` will be the first argument passed to `foo` when you use `pipe`.

Comment: Can we save this pipeline for future use, say if I pass a another df to follow same pipe functions?

Comment: @hanzgs Yes, wrapping the above answer in a function would make it usable for other dataframes. That function could even be called by `.pipe` itself.